# Random points all over inside of a circle

Tags: javascript, math, random, polar-coordinates

I'm using below code to randomly generate some x,y s that are located inside of a circle:

```
// r is distance from the center and a is angle
// R is radius of circle
// M is center

r = R * Math.random();
a = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();

x = Math.round(r * Math.cos(a) + M);
y = Math.round(r * Math.sin(a) + M);
```

the problem is while moving closer and closer to the center of the circle, the chance to get x,y in that location gets more and more.

But What I'm looking for is just to have completely random x,y all over in the circle. How can I achieve this?

Comment: An interesting discussion about this problem: [Bertrand paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to Jacobian, you have to take square root

```
r = R *  Math.sqrt(Math.random());
```

Comment: this is not a computationally efficient algorithm

Comment: Rejection sampling would probably be faster.

Answer (score 2):

To evenly distribute points within the circle, just pick random points in a square with side-length equal to 2R, and then discard any point that falls outside of the circle.

This can be done without *any* trigonometric or transcendental operations:

```
let x, y;
do {
    x = 2 * Math.random() - 1.0;  // range [-1, +1)
    y = 2 * Math.random() - 1.0;
} while ((x * x + y * y) >= 1);   // check unit circle

// scale and translate the points
x = x * R + Mx;
y = y * R + My;
```

In each pass of the loop about 21.5% of points will be discarded but this should still end up faster than using `sin` and `cos`.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate random x,y in a square of edge R and then check they lie inside the circle.

```
x = 2 * R * Math.random()
y = 2 * R * Math.random()
r = Math.sqrt((x - M)*(x - M) + (y - M) * (y - M))
if(r < R) {
    // show x,y
}
```

Comment: almost right answer - but compare to R^2 without the expensive `sqrt()` operation.   Also use e.g. `x = R * (Math.random() - 0.5)`

Comment: You are right that's less expensive - I was just trying to get across the idea

Comment: I think you have issues with (a lack of) negative coordinates.